# How to add tons of attributes in an Element with Python and Elementtree?

Tags: python, elementtree

Is it OK to use the following ?

```
ET.Element.attrib={'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

Or do I have to make a `for` loop using `ET.Element.set('x','y')` ?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I tried, both seems to work. (I'm just printing for the moment, I do not generate the XML yet). But somehow I feel like the ET.Element.attrib purpose is to return the dict, and it's not there to be edited with a new value. I'm trying to do something clean even if I'm a beginner.

Comment: You can [read the code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l171), there's nothing fancy there, it's pretty much just a wrapper around the `attrib` dict, so replacing it directly is fine.

Comment: Ok great ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

jonrsharpe comment above is the answer.
Just a detail though, I had to use `ET.Element.attrib=myDict.copy()` otherwise all my elements were pointing to the same dict in memory.